# “Unauthorized” error at Sign In in Jmeter script “Signature Expired” error message

Tags: jmeter, authorization

The application is based on AWS servers. There are no issues in recording the scripts, but, we are facing the below issues while running the same:

> "Unauthorized" error at Sign In

1. “Signature Expired” error message even after passing all the dynamic values for the requests for each iteration
2. Not able to correlate the “Signature” value getting passed in the request header as could not find in any of the above responses, also it changes for each request after Sign In.

Comment: is this also amazon autorization?

Comment: please share details of your script. Do you have a cookie manager for example? or how exactly the authorization is passed

Answer (score 0):

According to [Handling Dates in Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-date-handling.html) article:

> The time stamp must be in UTC and in the following ISO 8601 format: YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'. For example, 20150830T123600Z is a valid time stamp. Do not include milliseconds in the time stamp.

So most probably you will need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send `X-Amz-Date` header with the value like `${__time(yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z',)}` (current timestamp generated via [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function)

---

If above step won't help I believe you will need to reconsider your request building approach as it might be more complex that just correlation, check out [Signing AWS Requests with Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) for details (the above "timestamp" workaround will be still applicable)

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. Thanks for the suggestions, I will be trying Signing AWS Requests with Signature as have already added timestamp which isn't working.